# Preventing Multiple Login with same login credentials on Geonode

Tags: python, django, session

I'm just started with [genode](http://docs.geonode.org/en/master/) customization and sucked on this problem
how can I prevent user to login anywhere? I need to set 1 session per user which makes theme logout anywhere else if login a new one..
any one works with GeoNode
I works with django but really hard for me to find out how do that? cause just starting with python ;)
find out the login model here is the code :

```
@on_ogc_backend(geoserver.BACKEND_PACKAGE)
def do_login(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Take action on user login. Generate a new user access_token to be shared
    with GeoServer, and store it into the request.session
    """
    if user and user.is_authenticated():
        token = None
        try:
            Application = get_application_model()
            app = Application.objects.get(name="GeoServer")

            # Lets create a new one
            token = generate_token()

            AccessToken.objects.get_or_create(
                user=user,
                application=app,
                expires=datetime.datetime.now() +
                datetime.timedelta(
                    days=1),
                token=token)
        except BaseException:
            u = uuid.uuid1()
            token = u.hex

        # Do GeoServer Login
        url = "%s%s?access_token=%s" % (settings.OGC_SERVER['default']['PUBLIC_LOCATION'],
                                        'ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities',
                                        token)

        cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))

        jsessionid = None
        try:
            opener.open(url)
            for c in cj:
                if c.name == "JSESSIONID":
                    jsessionid = c.value
        except BaseException:
            u = uuid.uuid1()
            jsessionid = u.hex

        request.session['access_token'] = token
        request.session['JSESSIONID'] = jsessionid
```